# Which permission do I need to give to see all open tasks in the Maestro taskconsole

Tags: workflows

It is unclear to me which permission I do need to give to a specific role, to see all open tasks in the Maestro taskconsole, just like an admin sees all tasks.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to give the following permissions:

- Access Maestro Task Console
- View Outstanding Tasks

Comment: thanks for your answer. The View Outstanding Tasks permission does not appear in my list of all permissions (admin/people/permissions); is it set elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not using this module. I've just checked the `maestro_permission()` function in `maestro.module` file to find out which permissions it provides.

Comment: ok, I'll check. Thanks for your quick clarification